# UIStackView is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I was creating an ios project for learning purpose .When Stack my  likeUs image and facebook login button  together and try to put them in constrains, they disappear and when i set the distribution  to "Fill" and spacing to "40" that doesn't work .But the tutorial I have seen It works without any problem :(

And after putting constrains i cannot find my image and buttons and can not drag them to the right places

When set the distribution to "Fill Equally" then the image and button shows in the app when its build and run. But thats not what I want . I wanted to set the distribute "Fill"  :(

How can I solve the problem..

I am Using XCODE 7.3.1

Please help me out.. :(

when i set distribution to fill it looks like this:
[image]

when the distribution is fill equally it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: How do you like it to be ? Your second image shows the two elements as you like.

Comment: yes but it doesn't work when i set the distribution to fill but that should work fine... I want to use fill to look more accurate and why my image and button are not showing..????... even i can not drag them from where the point mark is ... :(